# ember I cannot append a view

Tags: view, ember.js

Im trying to insert a simple handlebars, like this, but there's so little support and the guide in the official page is so sad that I couldnt accomplish this.

```
<head>
    <!--HANDLEBAR-->
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="say-hello">
        Hello, <b>{{name}}</b>
    </script>

    <!--VIEW-->
    <script>
        var view = Ember.View.create({
            templateName: 'say-hello',
            name: "Bob",
        }); 
        view.appendTo('#templateHere');   //here I try to append the view
   </script>
```

In firebug I get the error: unable to find the template "say-hello"...........but I dont know why doesnt find it

Answer (score 1):

Finally I accomplished, I write the solutions here because I think that ember need more documentation and it's worth because is very interesting (and powerful):
The problem was that I create an object of my view before defining it. The right code is this:

....

```
    <!--HANDLEBAR-->
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="say-hello">
            Hello, <b>{{name}}</b>
    </script>

    <!--VIEW-->
    <script>
            App = Ember.Application.create();

            //DEFINE VIEW
            App.Myview = Ember.View.extend({
            templateName: 'say-hello',
            name: "Bob",
            });

            //CREATE VIEW>  
            App.myview=App.Myview.create();
            console.log(App.myview.get('name'));//only for debug

            //APPEND VIEW
            $(function() {
                App.myview.append('#templateHere');
            });

    </script>     

</head>
<body>
  <div id="templateHere"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In Ember class names should start with an uppercase letter and instance with a lowercase letter. For example `myView` would be and instance of `MyView`. I edited your post to reflect that.

Comment: It seems your desire to use append is indicative of some misunderstanding on your part?  Ember moves fast, so maybe you haven't read up on the latest changes?  see http://trek.github.com/